# How to create/reference another object from an object?

Tags: java, user-interface, object

Newby question here so I might be thinking about it incorrectly as I'm not very experienced with objects.
I have a 27x27 grid of objects that I created like this:

```
Square grid[][] = new Square[27][27];
```

Now, I need to get each of those objects into a container called `Environment1` via a method `add(ColonyNode, int int)` in such a way as every `Square` references a `ColonyNode` object and then every `ColonyNode` is added to the `Environment1` Container via the above method. 
The `ColonyNodeView add` method handles how they are placed in the container, hence the 2 `int` parameters. I just can't figure out how to link the Square Objects with the `ColonyNode` Objects and am looking for ideas.

What I tried so far but didn't work was:

```
for(int i = 0; i<grid.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <grid[i].length; j++){
            ColonyNodeView newSquare = new ColonyNodeView();
            Environment1.add(newSquare, i, j);
        }
    }
```

OK, I'm gonna do my best to explain the overall goal of this part of the program. Environment1 is a GUI container and Each ColonyNode will be added to that container to appear as a grid. 
Now, each Square is being updated by the rest of the program on certain variable values. I then want each square to reference a ColonyNode so that the overall GUI(environment1) can have that information pushed onto it.

Comment: `grid[i][j] = newSquare`?

Comment: whoa this is a confusing read. I can help you link each of the Square objects from the grid but i'm not able to figure out what's going on here

Comment: "Every Square references a ColonyNode". I think you meant every ColonyNode references a Square?

Comment: I'm writing an answer. Let me see if I can help you

Comment: You want every 'ColonyView' to be a part of a grid[i][j] of the Square datatype right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and help you but I'm interpreting your question in multiple ways. 
 
Let's see this statement "every Square references a ColonyNode". That seemed to put ambiguity in the question.

First of all, if you try to reference any of the data from the *grid* array, you will get a `NullPointerException`. Every Object in that array as to be initialized first, if you will, with a constructor. 
So the first change you should be making, is this:

```
grid[i][j]=new Square(); //Initializing the object. An object must be initialized before you can use it
```

Now, since you want the `grid[i][j]` `Square` object to be a part of your `ColonyNodeView`, just add a constructor which takes in a `Square` object as a parameter. I think overall what you need is something like this:

```
class ColonyNodeView
{
    //rest of your variables and references here
    Square sq; //Added a reference for a 'Square' object
    ColonyNodeView(Square a){
        this.sq=a;
    }
}

//In the other module
for(int i = 0; i<grid.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <grid[i].length; j++){
            grid[i][j]=new Square(); //Initialize it
            ColonyNodeView newSquare = new ColonyNodeView(grid[i][j]);
            //You have now 'linked' the square with the ColonyNodeView. 
            //you can access it by 'newSquare.sq'
            Environment1.add(newSquare, i, j); //Add the ColonyNodeView linked with the Square to Environment. Looks fine now
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a confusing read but from my understanding it sounds like you need to maintain a grid of squares within `Environment1`. Maybe the following structure will help you:

```
public class Environment(){
    Square [][] grid;
    public Environment(int i, int j){
        grid = new Square[i][j]
    }
    public void setSquare(int i, int j, ColonyNodeView c){
        grid[i][j] = c;
    }
    public Square getSquare(int i, int j){
        return grid[i][j]
    }
}
```

Now the interesting part. You can either have this:

```
public class Square{
}
public class ColonyNodeView extends Square{
}
```

or you can just get rid of the sqaure class all together and inside environment have a gird of `ColonyNodeView`:

```
public class Environment(){
    ColonyNodeView [][] grid;
    public Environment(int i, int j){
        grid = new ColonyNodeView[i][j]
    }
    etc . . . 
}
```

**Alternative**

You can also put your `ColonyNodeView` inside `Square`. So you could have the following:

```
public class Square(){
    ColonyNodeView v;
    public Square(ColonyNodeView v){
        this.v = v
    }
    //Sets and Gets
}
```

then when you call `setSquare`. You would do the following:

```
public void setSquare(int i, int j, ColonyNodeView c){
    grid[i][j].setColony(c);
}
```

Of course with this approach you would have to ensure that the grid is initialised properly.

Comment: I still can't figure out whether he wants "every square is referenced by a ColonyView" or every "every square is referencing a ColonyView"

Comment: As I said bit of a confusing read so I have just recommended this structure. Another approach would be to wrap `ColonyNodeView` inside a`Square`. So when you call `setSquare(...)` under the hood you would get something like `grid[i][j].setColony(c)`.

Comment: I think if he wants every Square to reference a ColonyNodeView, just add a constructor which takes in the ColonyNodeView argument in the Square class.

Comment: I proposed an alternative based on your comments @ShreyansSheth

Comment: Yes I have added my own brief answer and upvoted yours as well. Quite comprehensive